# Delay xmlHTTPresponse in ajax until result generate from backend

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I have this java script code for ajax and I'm having trouble of get response.

xmlhttp.status always become 0. I have repeatCallHr Servlet and getting parameters from jsp page as follows.

```
function loadResults() {
var tt = document.getElementById("StartDate");
alert(tt);
if (xmlhttp) {
    var query = "generateResults?name="
            + document.getElementById("name").value
            +"&startDate="+document.getElementById("StartDate").value
            +"&startTime="+document.getElementById("StartTime").value;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", query, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = loadStallsResponse;
    xmlhttp.send(null);
} else {
    alert("Browser not supported!");
}}

function loadStallsResponse() {
alert("come here");
alert(xmlhttp.readyState);
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
    alert("status is :"+xmlhttp.status);
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        resultList = [];
        if (xmlhttp.responseText.indexOf("Error") == -1) {
            alert("come to inside of status::")
            console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
            stallList = $.parseJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);
            populateStallData();
        } else {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    } else {
        alert("Error in loading salesman data");
    }
}}

function populateStallData() {
var table = "<tr><th>Date</th><th>Time</th><th>Skill</th><th>Total Call</th><th>Unique Calls</th><th>Repeat Calls</th></tr>";
for (var i = 0; i < resultList.length; i++) {
    table += "</td><td width='140'>"
            + resultList[i].date
            + "</td><td width='140'>"
            + resultList[i].time
            + "</td><td width='140'>"
            + resultList[i].skill
            + "</td><td width='140'><a style='color: -webkit-link; text-decoration: underline; cursor: auto;' href='http://"
            + resultList[i].totalCall
            + "</td><td width='140'>"
            + resultList[i].uniqueCall
            + "</td><td width='140'>"
            + resultList[i].repeatCall
            + "</td></tr>";
}
document.getElementById("ResultTable").innerHTML = table;}
```

In back end it takes more than 5 minutes to query the sql statement so that  xmlhttp.status return as 0 (I guess, but i'm not sure). How can I delay the xmlhttp response time until I generate the results in back end?

Comment: Please add the contents of loadStallsResponse()

Comment: I have edited the code by adding loadStallsResponse()

Comment: That looks alright. LoadStallsResponse will be run every time the response state changes. So from your question I understand that you never receive a ready state 4? Also not after the 5 minutes?

Comment: ReayState receive as 4 at the begging, But status always receive 0, not 200. that's the issue

Comment: Well your delay is well implemented but somehow your request is being interrupted that's why you are receiving a 0. The reason may be one of the many. There's a good answer on this [here](//stackoverflow.com/questions/3825581/does-an-http-status-code-of-0-have-any-meaning)